# FQL multiquery with event CREATOR does not work anymore

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I got several iOS apps that make an FQL multiquery to get infos about events by a certain creator.

```
query1: "SELECT eid, uid FROM event_member     WHERE uid = %@"

query2: "SELECT eid, name, venue, location, start_time, creator FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM #query1) AND start_time>%@ AND creator = %@"
```

up until yesterday, March 12th 2013 this worked just fine.
Now it returns an "unknown error".

if i change query2 to

`"SELECT eid, name, venue, location, start_time, creator FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM #query1) AND start_time>%@"`

it works again, but obviously i would have to update all apps to change this query, and i would love to circumvent this.

Is this by design?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/501594683237232?browse=search_5141df1ceefe73861636399